# Best way to generate HTML tags at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, tags

I'm working on a webshop and I want to generate some HTML where I can put the data that I retrieve from a database.

I loop through the list of movies with this code

```
foreach (Film f in listFilm )
{
  Response.Write(f.id);
  Response.Write(f.name);
}
```

What's the best way I should follow to generate this html code (with the data from the database included?)

```html
<div class="grid_1_of_5 images_1_of_5">
  <a href="ArtikelDetail.aspx"><img src="images/beauty_and_the_beast.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  <h2 id="film1" runat="server"><a href="ArtikelDetail.aspx">Beauty and beast</a></h2>
  <div class="add-cart price-details">
    <h4><a id="linkFilm1" runat="server" href="ArtikelDetail.aspx">Bekijk details</a></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an asp repeater... then if you want to format based on the data leverage row data bound event... it looks like you would need to have an on rowdatabound handler or get more data from the start to handle pricing

Comment: Jup, I solved it with a repeater. weird that I didn't think of that in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a Web server control, you can create the HTML at runtime and reuse it as well. Pass the object into the control and override the render and you will get the html.